# Python program gives no error or warning but neither doeas any window appear

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import*
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
import random
import time
import datetime

def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = Login(root)
    
          
class Login:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Billing Login System")
        self.master.geometry("1350x750+0+0")
        self.master.config(bg = 'cadet blue')
        self.frame = Frame(self.master,bg='cadet blue')
        self.frame.pack()

#Some code here
..(Login Conditions)
..
#

#After authentication this window should pop up
class customer:
    
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("eZ Billing System")
        self.root.geometry("1350x750+0+0")
        self.root.config(bg="cadet blue")
        self.frame = Frame(self.root,bg='cadet blue')
        self.frame.pack()

#some code here 



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This code works but the problem is that when i run the file no error shows up or warnings and neither does any window shows but if i run any other python program then this windows pops up and no problems.
I am new to this and cant figure out whats wrong.

Comment: Your code works on my computer.

Comment: yeah it works but in mine it just doesnt show up independently . I need to run another program in order to make it pop up. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you aren't creating main window instance.
That's why it is not showing error but not showing any output even.
Try adding this :

```
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yours welcome. Kindly upvote my aanswer it will help me to reach more people and answer more queries.

Comment: I have this root.mainloop() in all my python programs but they all do only appear after hitting the ALT key. Any idea what might be the reason? (Ubuntu 18.4, Python 3.6)

Comment: Your description isn't accurate. The main window is created, it's just that without having the program process events, the window is destroyed once the script ends.